# Arc cutoff in Matplotlib not working when figure size is big

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot ellipse in Matplotlib which is cutoff at some degrees (in other words, I'm trying to get an arc from circle) using Matplotlib's Arc functionality.

Let me put out here an insert of code which represents what I'm trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))

ax = plt.gca()

arc_element = Arc((0, 0), 475, 475, theta1=22, theta2=158, linewidth=2, zorder=0,
                color="k")

# Add the court elements onto the axes
ax.add_patch(arc_element)

plt.xlim(-252, 252)
plt.ylim(-65, 423)
plt.show()
```

This code produces following image: 
[image: Image with full circle]

But when the figure size is changed to:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
```

I get the wanted result which can be seen here:

[image: Image with arc only, correct result]

For reference, I'm using Python 3.6.3 and Matplotlib version 2.1.0.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 3.4 and `matplotlib 2.1.2`

Comment: Both are producing the same result for `Python 3.5.5` and `matplotlib 2.2.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after comment by DavidG. I updated matplotlib to newest version (2.2.2) and this problem is fixed